# Throw error for special character

Tags: validation, aura

I want to throw error message when there is a special character in the user input.I tried following,

```
var re = new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.\/]');
console.log('@@ special char:'+ re.test(userInput));
```

The debug always returns false. When the input is 123. or 1234 or @@12 etc.
If any special character is included along with . , error should be fired.

Comment: Two things I notice from your code. You're not checking for an `@` character in your regular expression and in your last sentence you say if any special chacters **along with** `. ,` is included, it should match the regex. This is also not the case with the pattern you've provided. Can you clarify?

You're interested in matching strings that contain both a `.` or a `,` and any of these `-!$%^&*()_+|~=```{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.\/@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some characters in your code (e.g. `@`). Instead, I'd specify which characters *are* allowed. For example:

```
var re = new RegExp('[^a-z0-9]','i');
```

Forbids anything other than letters and numbers.

Also, it's rather standard practice to write the regular expression in short form:

```
var re = /[^a-z0-9]/i;
```

The other syntax is really meant for dynamic regular expressions.

Also, note that some special characters have meanings depending on their location. For example, `[0-9^]` means "0 through 9 and caret (`^`)", while `[^0-9]` means "everything except 0 through 9."

You may want to take a tutorial on Regular Expressions, as they are relatively complicated, a tradeoff for their capabilities.